# Create PDF in Azure App Service Sandbox using wkhtmltopdf

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, .net-6.0, wkhtmltopdf, azure-appservice

So I have the task to create a PDF File from 3 HTML Files (header, footer, body)
Every HTML File is in the same local directory.

This is hosted on an Azure App Service (OS Windows / Standard Plan).

When I debugged it as a local API it worked without any problems, but as an Azure App service it is sadly not that easy.
The PDF doesnt get created and if the PDF is already available, it cannot access it, which makes actually quite sense for a PDF.

Note: I tried generating the PDF especially with the kudu CLI in this example since I can change the command/parameters way faster than hardcoding it or setting App Service variables and changing them constantly.

I'm not sure how the permissions of the file system are set and if the Azure App Service prevents the execution of an exe file for security reasons or the creation of files by programs without an error message.

Filestructure:

```
D:\home\site\wwwroot\wkhtmltopdf>ls
bmkcontent.html
bmkcontent_files
bmkfooter.html
bmkfooter_files
bmkheader.html
bmkheader_files
ignore
wkhtmltopdf.exe
```

Those **xxxxx_files** folders are containing .css and .js files for design and for smaller functions like counting up the number of pages.

The command looks like this:

> D:\home\site\wwwroot\wkhtmltopdf\wkhtmltopdf.exe --enable-local-file-access  --header-html D:\home\site\wwwroot\wkhtmltopdf\bmkheader.html --header-spacing 10 D:\home\site\wwwroot\wkhtmltopdf\bmkcontent.html --footer-html D:\home\site\wwwroot\wkhtmltopdf\bmkfooter.html --footer-spacing 10 D:\home\site\wwwroot\wkhtmltopdf\test.pdf  --enable-local-file-access --load-error-handling ignore

Errormessage from wkhtmltopdf when creating the pdf:

```
Warning: Failed loading page D:\\home\site\wwwroot\wkhtmltopdf\test.pdf (ignored)
```

Version:

```
D:\home\site\wwwroot\wkhtmltopdf>wkhtmltopdf --version
wkhtmltopdf 0.12.6 (with patched qt)
```

I tried around a lot with the dirctory names, parameters etc. but wasnt able to get it working.
Note: the double --enable-local-file-access thing works without any problem, I just tested with it locally

Local command:

```
--enable-local-file-access --header-html .\wkhtmltopdf\bmkheader.html --header-spacing 10 .\wkhtmltopdf\bmkcontent.html --footer-html .\wkhtmltopdf\bmkfooter.html --footer-spacing 10 C:\Users\public\Documents\aaaa.pdf --> works like a charm
```

Thanks to anyone sharing their thoughts and if you need further info, just comment it down and I'll append it into the original post.

Comment: You seem to be missing your code.

Comment: Yeah my Post is missleading a bit since I just use the Kudu console currently to retrieve the PDF but that doesnt work. My Code pretty much concentrates on the wkhtmltopdf command.. Was important to say the technologies I used tho since the API worked while running it on my localhost..

Comment: I seem to remember running executables in Azure, so I believe it should work. Do you know if wkhtmltopdf is running successfully / exits with exit code 0?

Comment: I probably think so - it executes without a problem. But I really think the main problem is creating the PDF.. I get the error message: Warning: Failed loading page D:\\home\site\wwwroot\wkhtmltopdf\test.pdf (ignored) while beeing on a localhost, it gets created -> Could be a permisson thing